# how to search in encrypted txt files with php

Tags: php, search, encryption

For a simple mailinglist, i store the data in `.txt` files.
In the txt files are 5 lines. 2 of them (which contain name and email) are encrypted. I stored name and email encrypted for security reasons.

This is how i search through the files:

```
/* EMAIL SEARCH */
$email_search = $_GET['email_search']; // get string from url for search
if (isset($email_search)) {
    $searchthis = strtolower($email_search);    
    $email_matches = array();

    $files = glob("subscribers/*.txt"); // Specify the file directory by extension (.txt)

    foreach($files as $file) { // Loop the files in the directory   {

        $handle = @fopen($file, "r");

        if ($handle) {

            $lines = file($file);           
            $grab_email = strtolower($lines[3]); // for sorting only

            while (!feof($handle)) {
                $buffer = fgets($handle);

                if(strpos(strtolower($buffer), $searchthis) !== FALSE) // strtolower; search word not case sensitive    

                    $email_matches[$file] = $grab_email; // put all lines in array  indexed by email

            }

            fclose($handle);
        }
    }

}
asort($email_matches);



<!-- search form -->
<form class="search-form form-inline" action="admin.php" method="GET">  
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email_search" placeholder="Search for..." />
        <div class="input-group-append">                
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>                          
</form>
```

This is how a txt file looks like:

```
id-5e0786c07c802 // id
Friends //category
ygkKcL/jz9U= // name (encrypted)
6gkKcL/jz9XuVRNayyIVcFbLw3ord0nc7IJj // email (encrypted)
902d95a9bf1c3f59a3996e4e7b4dec79 // token
```

Before, when the data was not encrypted, this search did work fine! 
But how can i search now while the name and email lines in each files are encrypted?

Comment: You'll have to read the file contents, parse it all out, decrypt the encrypted parts, reassemble it in memory, and search that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about search with encrypted value?

In your code, the `$_GET['email_search']` contains the word or value you are searching for. 
I do not know how your encryption looks like, but you can encrypt the word you are searching for, something like:

```
$email_search = openssl_encrypt($_GET['email_search'], $ciphering, $encryption_key, $options, $encryption_iv); // get string from url for search
```

Comment: I tried this, and i must confirm: this really works! I didn't thought about that option.